# How to hide error message when a key press in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following HTML and jquery function to validate inputs. I want to hide the error message when a press any key. so how to do it. please help me to write keypress function. thank you.

```js
       function Validate() {
            var isAllValid = true;
            $('.error').hide();
            $('#error').empty();
            $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');

            if ($('#FName').val().trim() == "") {
                $('#FName').focus();
                $('#FName').siblings('.error').show();
                $('#FName').parents('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                isAllValid = false;
            }
            if ($('#Email').val().trim() != "" || $('#Email').val().trim() =="") {

                var expr = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
                if (!expr.test($('#Email').val().trim())) {
                    $('#Email').focus();
                    $('#Email').siblings('.error').show();
                    $('#Email').parents('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                    isAllValid = false;
                }
            }
            return isAllValid;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="LName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">First Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="LName" placeholder="Last Name">
                <span class="error">**Please provide Last Name...</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email Address</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
```

Comment: add onchange event to input box

Comment: try to use``keyup``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    $('.error').hide();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<div class="error">please enter value</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [focusin](https://api.jquery.com/focusin/) [focusout](https://api.jquery.com/focusout/) events

```
$("#FName").focusin(function(){
  $(".error").hide();
});

$("#FName").focusout(function(){
  if($(this).val() === ""){
    $(".error").show();
  }else{
    $(".error").hide();
  }
});
```

As an example

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#FName").focusin(function(){
  $(".error").hide();
});

$("#FName").focusout(function(){
  if($(this).val() === ""){
    $(".error").show();
  }else{
    $(".error").hide();
  }
});

  
});


function Validate() {
            var isAllValid = true;
            $('.error').hide();
            $('#error').empty();
            $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');

            if ($('#FName').val().trim() == "") {
                $('#FName').focus();
                $('#FName').siblings('.error').show();
                $('#FName').parents('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                isAllValid = false;
            }
            if ($('#Email').val().trim() != "" || $('#Email').val().trim() =="") {

                var expr = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
                if (!expr.test($('#Email').val().trim())) {
                    $('#Email').focus();
                    $('#Email').siblings('.error').show();
                    $('#Email').parents('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                    isAllValid = false;
                }
            }
            return isAllValid;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="LName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">First Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="FName" placeholder="First Name">
                <span class="error">**Please provide First Name...</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email Address</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
```

Answer (score 0):

try `keyup`

```
$('.userInput').keyup(function() {
    $('.error').hide();
});
```

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/43oxq3p7/)